# Stubbing one method that calls a real method with jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine, filereader, sinon

I need to test a FileReader's onload, using Jasmine + Sinon.

This is the function to be tested:

```js
MyObject.prototype.uploadFile = function (file, callback) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = event => {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(event);
        }
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

And this is the test:

```js
describe('uploadFile', () => {
        it('should execute the callback', () => {
            let testFunction = jasmine.createSpy();
            let readData = {
                readAsDataURL: () => { 
                    this.onload();
                },
                onload: () => {
                }
            };

            file = new Blob(['image']);
            sandbox.stub(window, 'FileReader').returns(readData);

            component = sandbox.render(BioProfile);
            component.replaceImage(file, testFunction);

            expect(testFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I stubbed readData from FileReader (not sure if done properly, though), but I need a stubbed method to call a FileReader's actual method (onload) to be able to test.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stubbed `FileReader` incorrectly.

With object literals, `this` is the whatever context the object literal was constructed in.

**Unless** you use the shorthand notation introduced in `es6`.

So when you call `this.onload` inside `readAsDataURL`, its not trying to call the `onload` function on the `readData` object.

To do that:

```
let readData = {
    readAsDataURL() { 
        this.onload();
    },
    onload() {}
};
```